# базе данных стоит Nchar прописал и тут Nchar чего ругается?

Tags: c#

Код:

```
SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@№ загс", SqlDbType.Nchar, 10, "№ загс");
```

Ошибка:

```
Error   1   'System.Data.SqlDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Nchar'
```

В базе данных стоит Nchar прописал и тут Nchar
Чего ругается?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что NChar, ну подсказки же есть в любой IDE

Comment: @ yolosora спасибо!